# Filter Generic Collection Down to Records Containing Any Item in Collection of String

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

```
string rep = "Joe Shmoe"

ObjectSet<StoreData> storeData = edmContext.StoreData;
ObjectSet<CallData> callData = edmContext.CallData;
IEnumerable<string> repStoreData = storeData.Where(r => r.RepName == rep).Select(s => s.Location);

IEnumerable<CallData> repCallData = Here is where I want to filter down the callData collection down to just the records that have a location that is contained in the repStoreData collection
```

I've tried using some form of Join and Any but don't really understand the arguments those are asking for.

This was my best attempt and it is a no go.

`... = callData.Join(d => d.LOCATION.Any(repStoreData));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you don't have to use a join. You could just use:

```
callData.Where(d => repStoreData.Contains(d.LOCATION))
```

That's assuming `d.LOCATION` is a *single* string.

However, you probably don't want to do that with your current declaration of `repStoreData` as `IEnumerable<string>` - LINQ won't be able to turn that into a query to be executed *at the database*.

If you're able to declare `repStoreData` as `IQueryable<string>`, however, that would be more likely to work well. I don't know whether that will work with `ObjectSet<T>`, but I'd hope so.

Comment: Basically I have a Calls entity returning an ObjectSet of Service Call data including the location the call is at.  Then I have a StoreInfo Entity returning to me an ObjectSet will all my possible locations.  The IEnumerable<string> repStoreData is retrieving a string list of the locations from all possible locations that have that specific rep assigned.  I then want to find all the Service Calls in my callData list pertaining to any of those stores.  Does that clarify what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: I realized most of that - but in your sample code you're trying to use `d.LOCATION` as if it were a *collection*, when I assume it's really a single value. Have you tried the code I gave you, ideally changing your `IEnumerable` declarations to `IQueryable`?